# Changing CSS using alt and/or title

Tags: css, image, alt

I'm using Stylish add-on for Firefox and change the CSS of various pages to fit my wants and needs, but I kinda got stuck with a problem I'm not sure is solvable - so I'm turning here, where nothing seems unsolvable :)

This football manager site show teams that still play in a cup with different images. However, there are 5 different cups, so they re-use one of the images.

```
<img src="/Img/Icons/cupA.jpeg" alt="Spelar i Sverigecupen" title="Spelar i Sverigecupen" class="">

<img src="/Img/Icons/cupB.jpeg" alt="Spelar i Safircupen" title="Spelar i Safircupen" class="">
<img src="/Img/Icons/cupB.jpeg" alt="Spelar i Rubincupen" title="Spelar i Rubincupen" class="">
<img src="/Img/Icons/cupB.jpeg" alt="Spelar i Smaragdcupen" title="Spelar i Smaragdcupen" class="">

<img src="/Img/Icons/cupC.jpeg" alt="Spelar i Tröstcupen" title="Spelar i Tröstcupen" class="">
```

Is it possible with CSS to edit these to show five different images instead?

I have 5 different images for them. (cupA, cupB1, cupB2, cupB3, cupC [.png])

The cupA and cupC is no problem, but the three in the middle (cupB.jpeg) only have alt- and title-text that differ (not even a class as you can see). Can these (alt/title) be used with CSS somehow to separate these three cup images?

What I'm using (X= A, B or C obviously):

```
img[src$='/Img/Icons/cupX.jpeg']{
    padding-top: 13px !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 4px !important;
    width: 13px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    height: 0px !important;
    background-image: url('http://mypage.com/cups/cupA.png') !important;
    }
```

/M

Comment: So do what you did with the `src` attribute already, but with `alt` or `title` instead …?

Comment: so you want to add a background image to an `img` tag? Where should that background-image appear? :)

Comment: Depending on the HTML structure, you'd be able to use `nth-of-type`.

Comment: OMG I feel even more stupid then I look now, Thanks for pointing out the obvious for me /*facepalm*/
Dunno why I didn't even try that. Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

You can use different attributes in css selectors to target them

```
img[alt="Spelar i Safircupen"] {
    border: 10px solid pink
}
img[alt="Spelar i Rubincupen"] {
    border: 10px solid green
}
```

Comment: Thanks! As I already said -I feel even more stupid then I look now,
So obvious :)

Comment: No worries; we all get hung up on things!